# Object could not be converted into string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

code:

```
public function atualizarPorLocal( $acao, $novasRedes )
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $apagaObj = $em->getRepository( 'CommonBundle:AcaoRede' )->findBy( array( 'acao'=>$acao ) );

        foreach ( $apagaObj as $acao){
            if (!empty($acao))
                $em->remove($acao);
        }

        $em->flush();

    foreach ( $novasRedes as $idRede )
    {

            $new = new AcaoRede();
            $new->setAcao( $em->getRepository( 'CommonBundle:Acao' )->find( $acao ) );
            $new->setRede( $em->getRepository( 'CommonBundle:Rede' )->find( $idRede ) );
            $em->persist( $new );

    }

    $em->flush();
```

}

erro:

> PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class \CommonBundle\Entity\AcaoRede could not be converted to string in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 2794, referer: /app_dev.php/modulo/editar/col_soft

what can I do to work around this error?

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English language site.  Please remember to put your titles in English.

Comment: What are the types of `$acao` and `$novasRedes`? Are you sure there is a record object in DB for each one of your `find(...)` inside the foreach that you want to insert?

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but from what I'm understanding the variable $acao is an object ... but what can I do?

Comment: @BrunoMenezes have you read my answer?

Comment: thanks @barker.. but showed this error when I search by id

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Acao`'s `id`

```
$new->setAcao( $em->getRepository( 'CommonBundle:Acao' )->find( $acao->getId() ) );
```

Doctrine's `find` method is expecting `id` field, so it tries to convert your `$acao` to string using `__toString()` method. You have to pass `$acao->getId()` to make it work

Comment: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to CommonBundle\\Entity\\AcaoRede::setAcao() must be an instance of CommonBundle\\Entity\\Acao, string given, called in CommonBundle/Entity/AcaoRedeRepository.php on line 74 and defined in CommonBundle/Entity/AcaoRede.php on line 57, referer: http://localhost/cacic/app_dev.php/modulo/editar/col_patr

Comment: i print var_dump ($acao); show me: string(8) "col_patr"

Comment: @BrunoMenezes That means you are not passing the correct value; you may need to show us how do you get `$acao` or make sure the `$acao` is an object instance of your entity before passing to the function

Answer (score 0):

variable $acao was assuming a different value when entered in the second foreach 
solved this problem by changing the name of the variable.

```
foreach ( $apagaObj as $acaoObj){
        if (!empty($acaoObj))
            $em->remove($acaoObj);
    }
```